# Why am I obliged to use a GroovyMock in this case?

Tags: javafx, groovy, mocking, spock, testfx

Here is an MCVE:

**main.groovy:**

```
package core

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.stage.Stage
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader

class App extends Application {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader()
    static App instance
    FXMLController fxmlController
    void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        instance = this
        fxmlLoader.load( getClass().getResource("mainWindow.fxml").openStream() )
        primaryStage.show()
    }
}
class FXMLController {}
```

**testfx.groovy:**

```
package core

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Node
import javafx.stage.Stage
import org.testfx.framework.spock.ApplicationSpec

class FirstFXSpec extends ApplicationSpec {
    void start(Stage stage)  { }
    def 'at start, fxmlLoader should load mainWindow.fxml'() {
        given:
        App.instance = new App()
        App.instance.fxmlLoader = Mock(FXMLLoader) {
            getController() >> Mock(FXMLController)
        }
        Node mockNode = Mock(Node)
        // Stage mockStage = GroovyMock( Stage ){
        Stage mockStage = Mock( Stage ){

            show() >> null
        }

        when:
        App.instance.start( mockStage )

        then:
        true // details of test omitted
    }
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
javafx {
    version = '11.0.2'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
    testImplementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.3'
    testImplementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6'
    testImplementation 'org.testfx:testfx-spock:4.0.15-alpha'
}
application {
    mainClassName = 'core.App'
}
```

Details of the file src/main/resources/core/mainWindow.fxml are not important, but here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="core.FXMLController" >
    <children>
        <Label text="Some label"></Label>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

The above test fails. The real method `Stage.show()` is called and the fact that it is a mock is ignored.
If I change that from a `Mock` to a `GroovyMock` the mock method `show()` is used instead and the test passes.
Why does a normal Spock `Mock` get ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain Java `Mock`s cannot mock final methods and according to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show--) `Stage.show` is final. `GroovyMock`s work by using the groovy MOP and thus only work when called from groovy code, but they are more powerful in this regard.

Comment: Duh! Because it's **`final`**. Talk about a "schoolboy error". ... Thanks! ;-)

Comment: I just wanted to write the same answer because yesterday evening I was busy. I had added this line to the OP's test for illustration: `println "modifiers = " + java.lang.reflect.Modifier.toString(Stage.getDeclaredMethod("show").modifiers)`. The output will be: `modifiers = public final`.